# Expand log function with two terms

Tags: taylor-expansion

HOw can I expand ln(1+2/(A-1))? I think I need to use taylor series but the 1 is messing me up.
Should I just ignore the 1?

Comment: Details depend on what you want, powers of $A$ or powers of $\frac{2}{A-1}$ as in the answer by Abhra Abir Kundu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand it iff $|\frac{1}{2(A-1)}|<1$.

The expansion is $\displaystyle\ln(1+w)=w-\frac{w^2}{2}+\frac{w^3}{3}\dots=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{w^n}{n}$ ,for $|w|<1$

By the way this is maclaurin series.

Comment: Is ther anyway my problem could reduce to 2/(A+2/3)?

Comment: I dont think so ..... (I am not sure though)